# Switch case in Javascript with <% %> tags

Tags: javascript, jsp, conditional-statements

I need to execute something like below code in a JSP file :

```
<%! String value; %>
function setValue(val)
{
switch(val)
{
case 1:
<% value = "value1";%>
break;
case 2:
<% value = "value2";%>
break;
case 3:
<% value = "value3";%>
break;
}
<% //Java code  with use of value %>
}
```

The above code always end up in setting "value3" in the variable 'value'. Can anyone provide a solution to resolve this?

Comment: what does the rendered code look like

Comment: This is because you aremanipulating the class level variable on conditional statements in javascript which is not possible ..the jsp compiler will first evaluate the java code.. that's why `value=value3` always

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a client side switch to set a server side variable.

If you need value at serverside to change you need to change this to

```
<%! 
String value;
public String setValue(val)
    {
    String value="";
    switch(val)
        {
        case 1:
            value = "value1";
            break;
        case 2:
            value = "value2";
            break;
        case 3:
            value = "value3";
            break;
        }
    return value;     
 }
 //Java code  with use of value %>
```

if you need it client side you need to change it to

```
<%! String value; %>
function setValue(val)
     {
     switch(val)
          {
          case 1:
               value = "value1";
               break;
          case 2:
               value = "value2";
               break;
          case 3:
               value = "value3";
               break;
          }
<% //Java code  with use of value as a javascript variable name %>
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, in your 2nd piece of code above, how can i use 'value' variable of Javascript in my Java code?

Comment: Not. The moment the javascript gets evaluated its at the client. If you want it serverside you would need to do a json request to the server where it can be dealt in a seperate process.